# Ulimit setting for Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongoose

I found the normal ULimit setting for mongo db is as follows:

```
-f (file size): unlimited
-t (cpu time): unlimited
-v (virtual memory): unlimited [1]
-n (open files): 64000
-m (memory size): unlimited [1]
-u (processes/threads): 32000
```

Just wondering why the  "-u", recommendation is such high..

```
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/
```

How many process do mongo generally spawn for each CRUD operations?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Unfortunately this website is for programming questions only. This question, however, is about database administration and thus off-topic. You can, however, ask this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Philipp ok was not knowing it..

Comment: (re)asked, and answered here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49589/i-found-the-normal-ulimit-setting-for-mongo-db-is-as-follows/49590#49590 - no need to migrate